# How to integrate Bing Cognitive Web Search API in website of asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, bing-api, bing-search

I need to upgrade my code of Bing search API functionality to Cognitive Bing Web search API in asp.net MVC
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am ablt to acheive this, by following the below links.

https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2016/12/15/bing-search-in-c-a-step-by-step-walk-through-tutorial/
https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56b449fbcf5ff81038d15cdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this: a small [Bing search api client in C#](https://github.com/DamienDoumer/BingO/) I wrote in accordance with the code sample on this [page](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d). I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are quickstarts and tutorial for v7 Bing web search API. You can try here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/